# Was Loki ever caught for interfering with the Gjallarhorn during the Dark Reign event in Marvel Comics?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

During the Dark Reign event (just prior to the Siege storyline in Thor), the Asgardians have relocated to Latveria, where Doom (assisted by Loki) takes several of their number and dissects them to learn the secrets of their powers.  When this is discovered, the Asgardians naturally take up arms against Doom.  In doing so, the Gjallarhorn is sounded to recall all warriors to fight (including Thor, who is exiled from Asgard at the time).

Because Thor doesn't respond, Heimdall suggests that perhaps while Thor's mortal alter ego Donald Blake is on Earth, perhaps Thor cannot hear the horn.  It is explained later by Loki that he interfered with it to prevent Thor hearing it and coming to help fight Doom, although he only admits this to Doom directly, while indicating he's back in favour with Balder once more.

It should be a simple matter for the Asgardians to determine that the Gjallarhorn was interfered with, and that Heimdall's supposition was incorrect, since Volstagg, Hogun, Fandral and Sif also failed to hear the call and respond.

Was Loki ever taken to task over this?  From what I've read, it doesn't look like it, but I'm asking for a more authoritative answer than my own presumption.

Comment: One could presume he lied to Doom to seem more powerful and that simply Heimdahl's theory is correct.